# Azure data factory: Http file dataset for REST endpoint call

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have set up a dataset of type http file wherein I have setup my endpoint or relative URL. Now the problem is, this URl changes everyday.

Any idea on how can i automate this change without logging into the factory every day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I passed that change as a parameter in the pipeline and it worked.